# Is my VIEWSTATE encrypted?

Tags: asp.net, security, encryption, viewstate

I'm a little confused.  I haven't explicitly set the Web.config `<pages ViewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />`, and so [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateencryptionmode.aspx) says that it should default to `Auto`.  [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.viewstateencryptionmode.aspx) says that `Auto` should cause the viewstate information to be encrypted if a control requests encryption by calling the `RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption` method.  But, none of my controls call that method.  So it looks like my viewstate should, in fact, not be encrypted.

However, when I copy/paste the viewstate into one of the various [online](http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx) [viewstate](http://lachlankeown.blogspot.com/2008/05/online-viewstate-viewer-decoder.html) [decoders](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp), I'm told that the viewstate serialized data is invalid.  So, is my viewstate encrypted or not?  Is there some obvious way to tell?  Has the default ASP.net behaviour changed to encode the viewstate by defualt unless you disable it?

Comment: Just a note to say that online view state decoders will sometimes display "serialized data is invalid" if the viewstate contains user controls, regardless of whether encryption is being used or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its set to Always or auto, all control state would be encrypted.All controls calling `RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption` view state would be encrypted ir-respective of Auto/Always. If your 'custom control' needs encryption call this.

See this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerrequiresviewstateencryption%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> If you are developing a custom control that deals with potentially sensitive information, call the RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption method to register the control with the page and ensure view state for the control is encrypted.
>
> The entire page state will be
>   encrypted if the
>   ViewStateEncryptionMode is set to Auto
>   or Always.

Comment: Ahh.  "The entire page state will be encrypted if the ViewStateEncryptionMode is set to Auto or Always."  I hadn't noticed that, thanks.  I think I'll set it to Always just for good measure, but it should be encrypted when set to the default (Auto), in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Force it on, see if you get the same error from a decoder.

Force it off, see if it now decodes.

I think that will give you the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The default settings can be found on your machine.config, which is a general super config for all your web apps. with your web.config you can overwrite it. you can open one of your website and look inside.

Here you can find the machine.config:

```
%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<FrameworkVersion>\CONFIG
```